# How to trigger a jenkins build on specific node using pipeline plugin?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job called "TestPipeline". I want to trigger a build on 2 different slaves which labeled "tester1' and "tester2". And the pipeline script is quite simple here:

```
node('tester1') {
    build 'test_job'
}
node('tester2') {
    build 'test_job'
}
```

However when I run the TestPipeline job, the "test_job" won't run on the nodes which I assigned. But run on random node instead.

I'm wondering if I should set "Restrict where this project can be run" on my "test_job". So I set it to "tester" (The "tester" label contains both node "tester1" and "tester2"). But when I run the pipeline job again, the "test_job" runs on "tester2" twice. I should expect the job to run on "tester1" first and then run on "tester2". 
Why is that? Is it because the "node" step doesn't matter when it comes to which node the build step should be built on?

Comment: I've tried using [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin). But I'm stuck on how to specify the "node parameter" in pipeline script. The "Pipeline Syntax" only output like "build job: 'test_print', parameters: [<object of type org.jvnet.jenkins.plugins.nodelabelparameter.NodeParameterValue>]" whichever node I select.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Please see the bug [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36568). The solution is as follows.

1. Install Node and Label parameter plugin
2. In test_job's configuration, select 'This build is parameterized' and add a Label parameter and set the parameter name to 'node'
3. In pipeline script, use code:

```
build job: 'test_job', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'node', label: 'tester1']]
build job: 'test_job', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'node', label: 'tester2']]
```

And the job will be built as I wanted.

**However**, I think it is only a workaround. I still believe this is a bug. Because the node step should do its job instead of letting other plugins to do for it.

Comment: As [Jesse Glick](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=jglick) said: The label on node selects which node is allocated during its block. Wrapping build inside node makes no sense at all; the node context is ignored, you are just wasting an executor slot.
Using LabelParameterValue is the appropriate solution for the requested problem.

Comment: I have been struggling for a while now how to do step 2, but on another scripted pipeline job. I created a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55470917/how-to-define-a-label-parameter-in-a-parameterized-build-using-scripted-pipeline. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 9):

I did the same, but using Node parameter, so I can use nodes list running job directly, or running pipeline (in pipeline I use Choice parameter to have list of available nodes). So in my case:

1. Install Node and Label parameter plugin
2. In test_job's configuration, select 'This build is parameterized' and add a Node parameter and set the parameter name to `node_name`
3. In pipeline add Choice parameter, name it `node`, put there possible choices, so running pipeline you can choose on which node it should be run.

Code to insert into pipeline script:

```
build job: 'my_job', 
  parameters: [[$class: 'NodeParameterValue', name: 'node_name', labels: ["$node"], nodeEligibility: [$class: 'AllNodeEligibility']]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Here is how i got it working

1. create a 'job' 'test_job' with parameter type 'label' , name 'node', value can be any string. (this is the job to be triggered)
   .Set 'Restrict where this project can be run' to the label value
2. create a 'pipeline' with parameter type  "Node". From the pipeline section, use the following script

Note the label for test_job is ${env.NODE_NAME} which will be set by the pipeline based on user's choice

```html
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
              echo 'Building..'
              script {
                build job: 'test_job', parameters: [
                [$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'node', label: "${env.NODE_NAME}" ]
                ]
}}}}}
```

Comment: Cannie, is there any way i can parameterize the agent name from the Build Parameters, I was looking for something like this:

`pipeline
{
    agent ${'node'}
 
   }
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this on my installation, and it correctly ran each script on each node. 
You might want to check that you've configured your slaves correctly. I believe the documentation says they need to have the Launch slave agents via Java Web Start setting, you could verify that.

Comment: My slaves are launched via ssh. I guess maybe it will work if I change the settings to Java Web Start. So I did test again using Java Web Start. However, the result is the same. The job still runs on random nodes.