# Jenkins Pipeline: multiple jenkins instances

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, remote-access, jenkins-pipeline

I'm new to the pipeline plugin. In my environment, we've multiple teams and multiple jenkins instances set up. I like the fact that the pipeline job needs to be the 'top-level'.
However, most examples I can find rely on all jobs are configured on the same jenkins instance. **What if my jobs are on different machines?**

a simple webhook curl would trigger the job on the external machine, but wouldn't return any feedback on the status?

Here's my example pipeline config:

```
echo 'start Pipeline'

stage 'Build'
    build job: 'build'

stage 'Package tests'
    build job: 'test' # <-- this is on another jenkins server

stage 'Deploy'
    build job: 'deploy'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't get a satisfying answer to try out, but resolved it by doing more rewiring and putting all the job definitions in stages in the Jenkinsfile (no `build job ...`) and run an entire build in its own container (vs specialized containers for each step).

I think that is better practice for what I wanted to accomplish.
And I'm quite happy how my entire pipeline was simplified eventually.

Answer (score 0):

In the job configuration for 'test' you should be able to set required labels for the job via "Restrict where this project can run". The job should then automatically run on a Jenkins slave that has the respective matching label(s).

If you want to manually control which node exactly the job should run on then you would have to use the [NodeLabel Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin). See also this related [answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin) or this related [Jenkins issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36568?focusedCommentId=264023&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-264023).

**Update**

In case you want to trigger a job on a remote master (i.e. not a slave) you could use the remote access API or the [Parameterized Remote Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Remote+Trigger+Plugin).

Comment: The 'test' job I refer to, is known on a different jenkins instance (different url). I think what you're describing here is running the job on different slaves. afaik, I'll have to use [remote access](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) :(

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the use case then. I have updated my answer above to include an option for remote job execution via plugin.

Comment: I don't think that remote trigger monitors it as well? So how does my pipeline know how to not to move to a next 'stage' until the remote job has passed?