# Building a generic project on specific slaves in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have created a generic Jenkins project that, when built, gets the hostname of the machine on which the project is built. And so, I have not given the option `restrict where this project can be run` .

I have created a pipeline where I go to different slave machines using their labels and I want to run this generic Hostname project on that slave itself.

I have written the code as :

```
node('label1&&label2') { 
build job: 'Hostname'
} 
node('label3&&label4') { 
build job: 'Hostname'
} `
```

But the project is not running on the slave node that I have specified, but instead it is running either on the master node or any other available slave nodes.

So, how do I make a generic project run on only that node for only that particular build.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is this your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin

Comment: This was my exact problem. Thanks a ton !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to trigger a jenkins build on specific node using pipeline plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin)