# ensure jenkins pipeline using same node for download stream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Case:
I have 3 machine (A,B,C) for slave (sharing the same node label e.g 'build')

I have a pipeline which may trigger different downstream job. And i need to make sure that all the job and downstream job using same node (for sharing some file etc.). How i can do that?

a) I pass the node label to downstream but i am not sure if the downstream will take the same node.(parent job using slave "A" and i pass the node label 'build' to downstream job but maybe in downstream job it take slave 'B')

b) is that some way to get the runtime slave when the pipeline is executing, when i pass this slave name to downstream?

or is that any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to try [NodeLable Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/NodeLabel+Parameter+Plugin) Plugin.

Once installed, check '**This project is parametrized**' option and select '**node**' from '**Add Parameter**' drop down.

It will populate all nodes as drop down while building job with parameters.

It also have some other options which may help you.

Comment: As I understand it, this is not a solution for the problem described by the question.

Answer (score 1):

Most important question to me would be: Why do they need to run on the very same node?

Anyway. One way to achieve this would be to retrieve the name of the node in the node block in the first pipeline, like (CAUTION: was not able to verify code written below):

```
// Code for upstream job
@NonCPS
def getNodeName(def context) {
    context.toComputer().name
}
def nodeName = 'undefined'
node('build') {
    nodeName = steps.getContext(FilePath)
}

build job: 'downstream', parameters: [string(name: 'nodeName', value: nodeName)]
```

In the downtstream you use that string parameter as input to your node block - of course you should make sure that the downstream actually is parameterized in the first place having a string parameter named `nodeName`:

```
node(nodeName) {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even having static agents, workspaces are eventually cleaned up, so don't rely on existence of files in the workspace on your builds.

Just archive whatever you need in the upstream job (using the `archive` step) and then use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) in downstream jobs to get what you need there. You'll probably need to parameterize downstream jobs to pass them the reference to the upstream artifact(s) you need (there are plenty of selectors available in the Copy Artifact plugin that you can play with to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thx! actually i just need to make sure that the file are there during the build. so i think the copy artifact plugins will be worked for me as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are triggering child jobs manually from pipeline, then you can use syntax as this to pass the specific node label

```
build job: 'test_job', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'node', label: 'tester1']]
build job: 'test_job', parameters: [[$class: 'LabelParameterValue', name: 'node', label: 'tester2']]
```

current label of node you should be able to get this way `${env.NODE_NAME}"`

- found at [How to trigger a jenkins build on specific node using pipeline plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin)
- ref. to docs- https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-build-step/

But yes, if you want to manipulate with some files from this job in other jobs, then you will need to use eg. mentioned copy artifacts plugin, because workspaces of the jobs are independent and each job will have different content.