# How can we pass (parameter) three node slave variable by using same pipeline as a code in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

How can we pass (parameter)  three node slave variable by using same pipeline as a code in Jenkins.

I have three slave node on which I want to run the jenkins jobs and I want to integrate them in a single Pipeline as a code for achieving automation

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please provide some more information. It is very unclear what you are asking for. Do you have pipeline code that clarifies your problem?

Comment: No, I need to write the pipe line code. Suppose, I have jobs on two different node slave - slave1 and slave2. I want to trigger both the job by using pipeline as a code by passing the parameters. Thanks

Comment: I think you already have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin)

Comment: But, How can I select multiple node option using pipeline as a code. from above, I am only able to select single node value

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parametrized function in the job.

Refer: https://www.serverkaka.com/2018/08/build-jenkins-job-with-condition-and.html

Comment: But, I am not able to run on particular node. Can you give pipeline as a code for running two different jobs on two different nodes using parameter(node)