# Triggering a build on a specific node in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Pipeline jobs (test_a, and test_b).  test_a calls test_b (but test_b also has a generic-webhook-trigger, which has the same set of variables required (as Post Content Parameters); but I doubt that should affect the actual parameters since (in theory) the webhook parameter items are ignored when not being run via webhook.

I have followed [1] and the job is still being run on a random node.

Now in test_a's pipeline:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'l1'
    }

    stages {
       stage('Call b') {
           steps { 
               script {
                  env.use_node = 't1'
                  if (env.node_sel == '1') {
                      env.use_node = 't2'
                  }

                  sh '''echo ''' + env.use_node

                  build job: 'test_b',
                      parameters: [
                          [$class: 'LabelParameterValue',
                           name: 'node',
                           label: env.use_node],
                          [$class: 'StringParameterValue',
                           name: 'branch',
                           value: env.source_branch]
                      ]
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

The above pipeline is triggered with the following environment variable set:

- node_sel = 1

And in the `test_b` job, I have the following set:

1. "This project is parameterized"
2. Added "Label" parameter.
   2a.  Set Name to "node"
   2b.  Set Default value to Nothing
   2c.  Check "Run on all nodes matching label"

   2d.  (In [1], there is a mention of 'Restrict where this project can be run', but there
   is no option for that, and I'm assuming that's because this is a Pipeline job?)

The contents of test_b's pipeline,

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Cleanup WS') {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
            }
        }

        stage('Setup Environment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    print('Node: ' + env.NODE_NAME);
                    
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                sh '''set'''

                echo 'Hello World'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute test_a with environment variables "node_sel" = "1",  it echos "t2" in the log (so I know the environment variable env.use_node is set properly, and then it triggers test_b.

But it triggers on some other node instead of the specific "t2" one.

So I changed the agent line to:

```
   agent {
      label params['node']
   }
```

But it still executes to a random node (though since I only have two nodes, it doesn't execute on the specified node).

So I figured I might have specified it wrong in test_a, so I changed the build job parameters:

```
    build job: 'test_b',
      parameters: [
          [$class: 'LabelParameterValue',
           name: 'node',
           label: "${env.use_node}"],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue',
           name: 'branch',
           value: env.source_branch]
          ]]
```

But to no avail so I'm stumped.  I tried switching the sequence of the parameters; but it makes no difference.  Ditto with the sequence of the "This project is parameterized" sequence of parameters (before it was the last parameter.  I tried it with the "Label" parameter as the first, still no go).

[1] -- [How to trigger a jenkins build on specific node using pipeline plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38240943/how-to-trigger-a-jenkins-build-on-specific-node-using-pipeline-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite confusing to me as I finally got it working via the following changes (which goes against the linked post).

In `test_a`'s job:

```
 build job: 'test_b',
      parameters: [
          [$class: 'LabelParameterValue',
           name: 'label',
           label: env.use_node],
          [$class: 'StringParameterValue',
           name: 'branch',
           value: env.source_branch]
          ]]
```

And in `test_b's job definition:

- Changed the LabelParameter's Name from `node` to `label`.

I'm now questioning whether or not this answer should also just be posted in the linked question.